# Need JET 4.0 Drivers

Tags: excel, ms-office, oledb, jet

I am using an ExcelProvider with Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 and am getting the Cannot Find Installable ISAM from the production machine.  Windows Server 2003.

I've searched and search for this download.  I've Office installed on the Dev machine, so I'm sure that's why it works fine on my end.  But I can't install Office on the Production machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed IMEX=1; from the string and it worked fine.  Weird, at one time it worked fine with this on there.  Maybe it has something to do with the versioning, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that the Jet provider is not already on the machine?  The error message most often occurs as a result of a badly formatted connection string rather than the absence of the driver.  Check for typos in the connection string.